# Finding forums based on a user's permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm implementing a forum system called rBoard. Code is viewable at http://github.com/radar/rboard. I've reached an impasse with the permissions code that I've been trying to implement and I've decided to turn to the all-knowing, ever-caring Stack Overflow to solve this issue.

Relevant information is thusly:

**Category model**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :permissions
  has_many :groups, :through => :permissions
  has_many :forums
end
```

**Forum model**

```
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :permissions
  has_many :groups, :through => :permissions
  belongs_to :category
end
```

**Group model**

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_users
  has_many :users, :through => :group_users
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User"
end
```

**Permission model**

```
class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :forum
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :group
end
```

**User model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Rboard::Permissions
  has_many :group_users
  # Note: I am using nested_has_many_through
  has_many :groups, :through => :group_users
  has_many :permissions, :through => :groups
end
```

**Permissions module**

```
module Rboard::Permissions
  THINGS = ['forum', 'category']

  def self.included(klass)

    klass.class_eval do
      # Here we can pass an object to check if the user or any the user's groups
      # has permissions on that particular option.
      def overall_permissions(thing = nil)
        conditions = if thing.nil?
          THINGS.map do |t| 
            "permissions.#{t}_id " + (thing.nil? ? " IS NULL" : "= #{thing.id}") + " OR permissions.#{t}_id IS NULL"     
          end.join(" AND ")
        else
          association = thing.class.to_s.downcase
          "permissions.#{association}_id = #{thing.id} OR permissions.#{association}_id IS NULL"
        end

        permissions.all(:conditions => conditions)
      end

      def can?(action, thing = nil)
        permissions = overall_permissions(thing)
        !!permissions.detect { |p| p.send("can_#{action}") }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Hopefully with this you should be able to figure out the fields in the permissions table are like `can_see_forum` and so on. Extra fields are `forum_id`, `category_id` and `default` (default is currently unused)

What I want to know is, how can I find all the forums a group can see? Generally if a forum_id is set, then that permission applies. If there is only one permission for that group without specifying a forum_id or category_id then it is seen to be global to everything. I'm completely at a loss here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need something like (the fictitious) acts_as_permissible. Some mixin that can be applied to different kinds of objects -- in this case groups and users -- that allows you to test authorization. A possible usage might be:

```
class Group
  include Acts::Permissible
  acts_as_permissible
end

module Acts
  module Permissible
    def self.acts_as_permissible
      begin
        Role.find(:all).each do |role|
          define_method "can_#{role.access_type}?" do
            self.send('has_role?', role.access_type)
          end
        end
      # Since we're possibly running within the scope of Rake, handle the case   
      # where the roles table doesn't exist  
      rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid => e        
        RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.error "Statement invalid while adding Role methods to User. Is the Roles table present in the DB?\n" + e.inspect
      end
    end
  end
end
```

WARNING: This is *air code*! Never tested. But you could mix something like this into your User and authorize against the same roles as your Group model.